# Doctrine replaces last query character with bracket

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have doctrine query like this:

```
$users = $q->select('ga.publisherId, ga.pageViews')
    ->from('App_Model_GoogleAnalytics ga')
    ->where('ga.dateFrom = ?', array($date))
    ->addWhere("ga.type = 'daily'")->groupBy('ga.publisherId')
    ->having("SUM(ga.pageViews)>100")
    ->fetchArray();
```

It looks fine. But when executed the MYSQL code looks like this:

```
SELECT o.publisherid AS o__publisherid, o.pageviews AS o__pageviews FROM
googleanalytics_ga o WHERE (o.datefrom = '2014-03-01' AND o.type = 'daily') 
GROUP BY o.publisherid HAVING SUM(o.pageviews)>10)
```

Looks like doctrine "eats" last 0 in 100 and replaces it by unnecessary ")". Why it is happening? I am using doctrine doctrine 2.3.x-dev and php 5.3.

Comment: Is it ok with adding free space after your 100 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put space between ) and > in having clause.

`$users = $q->select('ga.publisherId, ga.pageViews')
    ->from('App_Model_GoogleAnalytics ga')
    ->where('ga.dateFrom = ?', array($date))
    ->addWhere("ga.type = 'daily'")->groupBy('ga.publisherId')
    ->having("SUM(ga.pageViews) > 100")
    ->fetchArray();`

Comment: Right. Seems like doctrine parsing problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this should to the trick:

```
->having('SUM(ga.pageViews) > :sum_page_views');
->setParameter('sum_page_views', 100)
```

hope this helps :-)